# Traduire "I see your point" sans anglicisme?

Tags: anglicismes

Comment traduire "I see your point" en français ?

- *je vois ton point* est un anglicisme
- *je comprends ton point de vue* n'a pas exactement le même sens
- *je vois ce que tu veux dire* est un peu vague

Comment: En bon Québecois, on dit, "Ouuaaaiii, j'vois ben."  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pour moi "*Je vois ce que tu veux dire*" est très bien. J'aime bien aussi "*Je vois où tu veux en venir*" mais tu vas trouver qu'il est aussi vague j'imagine. Dans le cadre d'un débat on pourrait trouver des choses comme "*Je comprends votre argument*"

Tous les idiomes n'ont pas forcément de traduction qui soit à la fois juste et du même registre, parfois il faut une traduction différente au cas pas cas. Il y a aussi des choses en Français qu'on ne peut pas traduire correctement.

Mais je maintiens que "*Je vois ce que tu veux dire*" fonctionne très bien, même pour un argument bien formé.

Comment: Je crois bien que la combinaison de tes 3 propositions (+ le "tu marques un point" de @Kii, pour une argumentation plus informelle) recouvre les différents sens du *point* anglais !

Answer (score 3):

The following comes to mind:

> Je vois où tu veux en venir.

I think that this one is specific enough to serve as a replacement for "your point". Because:

> Je vois où tu veux venir (de tes propos).

Answer (score 2):

> Tu marques un point

Pour signifier que l'on comprend bien l'argument de l'interlocuteur et qu'on adhère à ses propos.

Comment: _I see your point_ n'implique pas qu'on est d'accord.

Comment: @mouviciel : Implicitement, on reconnaît la validité du raisonnement. On ne le nie pas.